# Is it Possible to define an alternative get_absolute_url for mobile user agent?

Tags: django

Is it possible to define an alternative `get_absolute_url` in one model? This question may seem strange but this is what I want to achieve:- I want to be able to redirect request from mobile users to a different template using Generic views without explicitly indicating the template path. I hope this is clear?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can overload the get_absolute_url of the model by defining it in your model. It takes no arguments, but since is a python function, you can test if the user is using a mobile app to enter in your website and render the template accordingly. See it in [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#get-absolute-url).

By the way, it is very normal to change the get_absolute_url() function, for instance if you have a view specific for that model, one option is the get_absolute_url() returns the [reverse](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/urlresolvers/#django.core.urlresolvers.reverse) of that view.

Hope this helps.